# Error Creating Business Intelligence Center

Tags: sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, performancepoint

I am receiving the following error when creating the Business Intelligence Center site collection.  From what I can tell the Performance Point feature is installed and activated so I am not sure why this error is showing. Thanks for the help.

```
Error 
Feature with Id '8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: bf1ccdbf-e271-4337-a801-f356cd89c08d 

Date and Time: 8/3/2011 6:33:06 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the two following features for it to work :

- SharePoint Server Publishing infrastructure
- PerformancePoint Services Site Collection Features

You should also note that this feature is only available in ***SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise Edition***.